# Simple CSS transition does not execute

Tags: css, css-transitions

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yJnKd/2/)

```
<a href="#">hover</a>
<p>Text here</p>
```

I want the `<p>` to fade in and slide in when the `<a>` is hovered. Problem is, with the CSS in the demo, the `<p>` just "pops" in rather than animating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transition` shorthand doesn’t support multiple properties in the same place:

```
transition: max-height .5s ease, opacity .5s ease;
```

You also need `overflow: hidden` to make it look like it’s sliding. [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/yJnKd/4/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to comma seperate the properties you want to transition:

```
p {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .5s ease, opacity .5s ease;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pZngX/

Comment: This [actually makes the first transition last 0s](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/pZngX/1/).